# Java, does the method with callback considered async?

Tags: java, concurrency, callback

I have created interface with one method:

```
public interface ResultCallback {
   void onResult(String message);
}
```

And I have object with method that has interface as parameter:

```
public class Command() {
  public void methodWithCallback(int param1, String param2, ResultCallback callback) {
      // There are some calculations
      callback.onResult(param2);
  }
}
```

Then In my Main Java file I write this:

```
public class Main() { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Command c = new Command();
       c.methodWithCallback(int 0, "SOME STRING", new ResultCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(String str) {
         // work with str
         outsideMethod(str);
       }
      });
   }

   public void outsideMethod(String str) {
      // some code
   }
}
```

Does this code can be considered as async? And is it safe to call `outsideMethod` to handle params?

Comment: No you are simply calling the callback synchronously.

Comment: @JohannesJander So is it safe to call `outsideMethod` inside `onResult`?

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it async is the following:

```
public class Command {

    private ExecutorService iExecutor;

    public Command(ExecutorService executor) {
        iExecutor = executor;
    }

    public void methodWithCallback(final int param1, final String param2, final ResultCallback callback) {
        iExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // There are some calculations
                callback.onResult(param2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You have to know what you're doing if using threads. Things have to be thread safe etc depending on how you are doing stuff. To run Command on a single thread create a single thread Executor and pass same Executor to all Commmand, like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Command command1 = new Command(executor);
Command command2 = new Command(executor);
```

Answer (score 2):

As said, it is not async. For the call to be async the method should execute on another thread.

You can't call outsideMethod since it's called from a static method. You need an instance of main to be able to call outsideMethod. If it is safe or not depends on what the code is doing.

Comment: What do I need to add to my `Command` class, in order to make it work as async. Can you provide example. This could help for others too.